# How to add a query parameter from an abstract state in ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to add a query parameter to a URL in an abstract state?

I need a user ID to be available to every child state, but the method of obtaining that ID differs, depending on whether the user is logged in.

I don't want to use a ui-router `resolve`, because I need the ID available to all controllers via dependency injection. So a deeply-nested directive should be able to fetch this ID by injecting `$stateParams`.

I'm using Angular 1.5.5 and ui-router 0.3.0.

Comment: You can add url parameters, not query parameters. You add them to your abstract state like you would to any other state then access them in all child states through $stateParams.

Comment: @Nirri Interesting. How do you do this? Do you mutate $stateParams?

Comment: No, all parameters are available from parent states in $stateParams. And even if you used resolve, you could use dependency injection in child controllers. (Anything you would define in the resolve would be available in child states - via inheritance)